# Callback function with a truthy value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, callback, truthiness

This is my very first post on StackOverflow, and I would be grateful if you could help me clarify, at a conceptual level, what's happening in the following JavaScript function. So, I've been practicing the language for a while, and I'm now diving a little deeper in the world of functions. Here is my dilemma:

```
function findEven(array, callback) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (callback(array[i])) {
            console.log(array[i]);
        }
    }
}
function isEven(num) {
    return num % 2 === 0;
};
findEven([2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 12], isEven);
```

Now, I understand what this does, and I know that I could achieve the same result with a simple `.forEach()`. What I would like to get, though, is what the conditional `if (callback(array[i]))` is doing. Is it establishing if the callback function is truthy (as per the MDN glossary, all values are truthy unless they are defined as falsy)? And why is that, because I added the callback function, after defining it, in the final array? In fact, if I try to strip it off, it returns the error: "callback is not a function". Can you confirm that?
I hope I posted my question in a meaningful way, thanks in advance!

Comment: No, it doesn't check whether `callback` is truthy. It does *call* the function you passed as an argument and checks whether the return value of that call is truthy.

Comment: Just replace `callback` with `isEven` to understand what the loop is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conditional `callback(array[i])` verifies if the value of `isEven()` function passed as `callback` evaluates to `true/false` for `array[i]`.

```js
function findEven(array, callback) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        console.log(i, array[i], callback(array[i]));
        if (callback(array[i])) {
            console.log(array[i]);
        }
    }
}
function isEven(num) {
    return num % 2 === 0;
};
findEven([2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 12], isEven);
```

If you print the `console.log` statement, you will see, for the values, `callback()` evaluates to `true`, gets printed in console. `False` value are ignored.

Comment: Agh, you were 30s faster. My answer also contains the explanation of that error so I can keep it

Answer (score 0):

The syntax

```
if(callback(parameters))
```

checks whether `callback(parameters)` returns a thruthy value. In your case, for an even number, your function returns `true`, which is, of course, truthy.

Also, if you remove your callback function from the parameters in your call to `findEven`, then the value of `callback` will be `undefined`. Then trying to call it like `callback(array[i])` will give that error since `undefined` is not callable (you can not do `undefined()`)